# Why is the following space not complete

Tags: complete-spaces

why is (C[0,1],||.||4) not a complete space?

Since it is closed, is it because of the norm 4? I know it should be complete if for every sequence its limit is in the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closedness depends on the choice of topology. Your space is closed under topology induced by uniform norm ($\|f\| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$), but it is not closed under the topology induced by Lebesgue norm $$\|f\|_4 = \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^4dx\right)^{1/4}.$$
In order to show that, you can find a counterexample to definition of closedness. For example, try to build a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ such that they converge in the sense of the norm $\|\cdot\|_4$ to a discontinuous function $f$. You might want to start with a function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\ge 0.5\\0,&x<0.5.\end{cases}$$

Comment: so under that topology the space would actually be open thus not complete?

Comment: @SoHCahToha No, not necessarily open. Just "not closed".

Comment: is that sufficient to know that is it not complete since not closed hence not all limits of converging sequences will be in my set?

Comment: @SoHCahToha exactly.